# How do I detect No(t)Scripts?

Tags: javascript, noscript

I have a `<noscript>` block in my [header](https://makeyourlaws.org), just within the body, to warn people that my site requires JS.

However, testing in Chrome w/ the NotScripts plugin blocking the site's JS, the `<noscript>` block doesn't render. :(

What would be a good way to make the block a bit more bulletproof?

The site works only partially without JS; some things (e.g. Stripe payments) won't work at all, some will just be degraded. I do want to partially support no-JS mode (e.g. for a Tor hidden site version that's privacy-enhanced but partially functionality-crippled), so I want to just display a warning, not disable the site altogether.

Comment: noscript tags work in chrome, however there is a known issue (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232410) that the html is rendered as code if you are already on the page and disable scripts. Does the problem still happen if you disable scripts in chrome's settings, and then refresh the page a couple of times?

Comment: You can't detect it. `noscript` tags only work if Javascript is disabled at the browser level. If there is a plugin blocking your scripts the noscript tag won't render, but you can't write any scripts for detection either.

Comment: You could perhaps do `<h1 id="nojs">Site requires JS</h1> <script>document.removeChild(document.getElementById("nojs"))</script>`? The idea is that the `<h1>` is written to the DOM, and then JS immediately destroys it. This might have some compatibility (or other!) problems; I haven't tested it.

Comment: @apsillers Yes, but can I do that in a way that wouldn't reflow? I guess one possibility is like `<script>[make nojs div css-displaynone</script><nojs div>`

Comment: I'm not sure. `<script>` tags are executed when they are parsed. If this is near the top of your HTML page, most of the HTML hasn't been *parsed* yet, let alone *rendered*, so I'm not sure it would cause a significant reflow (since there's barely been a "first flow"). I don't really know anything about reflow, though, so get a second opinion.

Comment: If the `nojs div` is `position:absolute;z-index:zillions`, then it will not cause a reflow.